# What does selecting a page for GDPR privacy actually do?

Tags: privacy

I get that you can generate a sample privacy page with the new GDPR update. I don't understand what it actually does? Is there an API endpoint or something? When you "select an existing page" what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will add a link to the selected page to wp-login.php and a link to it is included in the Erase Personal Data confirmation email.

It also makes it easy for themes and plugins to link to it using the `the_privacy_policy_link()` function. The default themes all use this to add a link to the selected page to the footer.